# Modifying the Request parameters throws Internal Server Error

Tags: rest, python-2.7, eve

When using the Python Eve Database hooks I am trying to modify the request parameters on a post call I am getting the below error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>
Internal Server Error
</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your     
request.Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the     
application.
</p>
```

And when I remove the code fragment to modify the Request Parameters the resource is created successfully.

Please find the code snippet as :-

```
__author__ = 'sappal'

from eve import Eve
import time

def insert_people(items):
  # retrieve request parameter, if present
  print items['userid']
  print items['email']
  items['userid']= "Tushar_Sappal" + str(int(time.time()))
  items['email'] = "sappal.tushar"+str(int(time.time()))+"@gmail.com"
  print items

# Creating the instance of the EVE Application
app = Eve()

app.on_insert_people += insert_people

if __name__== '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` is a list so you should update your code like this:

```
def insert_people(items):
    for item in items:
        item['userid']= "Tushar_Sappal" + str(int(time.time()))
        item['email'] = "sappal.tushar"+str(int(time.time()))+"@gmail.com"
```

While in development, you usually want to run your application in debug mode, so you can get a full stack-trace with the error:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Just make sure to disable the debug mode when running in production.

Comment: @tushar_sappal please accept and eventually upvote the answer if it provided a valid solution for you :)

Comment: Sorry I was busy implementing your solution.. I will surely upvote .. :) :)